# Route53 - Shared Private Hosted Zone across multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

So i have 2 Accounts (Account A and Account B)

Account A has a Private Hosted Zone names `MyAccounts.net` that is associated with Account A's VPC.

I added Account B's VPC to Account A's Private Hosted Zone and it works all fine.

Now when i make a Route 53 API Call from Account B Lambda as below, i do not get the Private Hosted Zone (`MyAccounts.net`).

```
route53 = boto3.client('route53')
hosted_zones = route53.list_hosted_zones()
```

This returns `Nothing`

How do i get the list of PHZ associated with Account B's VPC?

Answer (score 2):

You can't describe another account's resources from different account directly. You can create an IAM User and give that user Route53 access on account A, you can use boto3 with account A user's credentials.

Comment: Technically Route53 has VPC id of Account A and Account B so it is shared between the two accounts so does it not really belong to both of them?

Comment: No, route53 is a different resource, you can't describe vpc of another account neither. If you are describing resources you must use another account's iam credentials.
You can only acces to resources in that vpc.

Comment: Can I do a cross account role and achieve the same thing?